# writing a EXECUTE statement in tOracleRow component using context variable

Tags: sql, variables, execute, talend

I am trying to write an EXECUTE statement in `toraclerow`.

At each iteration the string is prepared dynamically from the flow. Here I am not discussing how I have prepared the string. But once prepared the entire string is stored in a single context variable. For example I have the following string stored in a context variable at a given iteration number.

```
context.FinalString = "Insert into TargetTableName (columnA, columnB) 
                            SELECT Col_A, Col_B 
                            FROM SourceTableName"
```

I am trying to execute this string in the tOracleRow component using the following statement:

```
  "EXEC SQL EXECUTE '"+context.FinalString+"'"
```

On running the job I am getting the following error.

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Kindly suggest a solution. Is there a way to execute a sql statement stored as a string in a context variable?

Answer (score 1):

try to execute by removing text EXEC SQL EXECUTE ..just simply the text should be the statement  - insert into table select col from table...
or 
update table set column=value where ...

you dont need exec sql execute text here.